# What is the .ttf font for default LaTeX font?

Tags: fonts

What's the .ttf version of the default font used by \LaTeX?

Trying to make a quick screenshot edit of LaTex screenshot in Photoshop, but having a hard time to get fonts to match up.

Comment: You can find the answer here : http://superuser.com/questions/42420/is-there-a-latex-like-font-for-my-other-documents